# Html.fromHtml or Spannable,what is best?

Tags: android, spannable

hello i want change color in my textview, 
there is two way :
Html.fromHtml And Spannable.
whats is better? 
what way is faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Html.fromHtml` is slower because the full text is parsed as an HTML. It actually involves the conversion from HTML to a text.

`Spannable`, on the other hand, is a lot more load-free because you just have to [attach or detach the markup object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html). No conversions involved.

Therefore, go with `Spannable`, it's much faster than the html alternative.